Multilevel/mixed model when group is missing for some of the data
A client has given me a dataset of corn samples gathered from different loads of corn that were delivered to a grain elevator. They are interested in whether the concentration of different fungal toxins in the grain is related to the nutritional content of the grain. There are several hundred samples. They come from different regions (US states). Unfortunately state of origin is only known for about half the samples. I assume that many of the samples come from the same farms and thus aren't independent, so I wanted to fit a multilevel model. I don't know what farms they come from, so state of origin is the only possible variable I could use to group the data. What should I do in this case, when the group identity is missing or not known for some of the data?
My initial thought was just to forget about the multilevel structure and treat every sample as independent but that doesn't seem ideal. I guess you could also fit the random intercepts for the groups you do know, and treat all the other unknown ones as each belonging to their own group? Is that an acceptable way to proceed? Any insights would be appreciated.
